# How to do sum and assign value in F#?

Tags: f#

What is wrong with code when I run this code it doesn't run if statement and there is warning on assigning value to player variable. I'm new at F# so please guide me on how I can sum random number and player value and assign it to player and then if statement works.

```
...let player=0
   let dealer=0
   for i = 1 to 10 do
   let randnum=randomCh()
   let randnum2=randomCh()
   player=randnum+player
   dealer=randnum2+dealer
   Console.Write("Player revealed cards.\n")
   playercards()
   Console.Write("Dealer revealed cards.\n")
   playercards()
   if player>=21 || dealer>=21 then result()...
```

Comment: If you don't indent your code correctly, it will not work correctly; F# has indentation-significant syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values are immutable in F#. If you want to declare mutable variable, use `mutable` keyword

```
let mutable player = 0
let mutable dealer = 0
```

To assign new value to mutable variable you should use `<-` operator (`=` is a comparison)

```
for i = 1 to 10 do
    player <- player + randomCh()
    dealer <- dealer + randomCh()
```

Further reading [Values in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/)

In F# you can use `printf` instead of `Console.Write`. Consider also using immutable values with recursion instead of loop with mutable variables. I don't know rules of blackjack or whatever game you are creating, but here is an example of recursive approach:

```
type GameResult = Player | Dealer | Draw

let rec notblackjack player dealer round =
    if player >= 21 then Dealer
    elif dealer >= 21 then Player
    elif round = 10 then Draw // in this game we have draw on round 10
    else blackjack (player + randomCh()) (dealer + randomCh()) (round + 1)

notblackjack 0 0 1 |> printfn "%A"
```